# SQL Query simplification (EXPLAIN COST 58)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, explain

Can someone help in simplifying below query. Cost of it shows as 58.

b.dueDate and b.tID are composite key.
a.tID is primary key and foreign key between table 1 and 2.

```
SELECT test.tID, test.sor_acct_id, test.pmt, test.status FROM   ct.tab1 a, 
   (SELECT a.tID, a.sor_acct_id, b.dueDate, b.amt, b.status, a.pmt, 
           Row_number() OVER ( partition BY a.tID ORDER BY b.dueDate DESC) AS rn 
    FROM   ct.tab1 a 
           INNER JOIN ct.tab2 b 
                   ON a.tID = b.tID 
    WHERE  a.tID IN (SELECT a.tID 
                              FROM   ct.tab1 a 
                                     INNER JOIN 
                                     ct.tab2 b 
                                             ON a.tID = 
                                                b.tID 
                              WHERE  a.status = 'E' 
                                     AND a.pmt IS NOT NULL 
                                     AND a.pmt <> '{}' 
                                     AND b.dueDate > CURRENT_DATE - 4 
                                     AND b.dueDate < CURRENT_DATE) 
           AND b.dueDate > CURRENT_DATE - 1 
   ) test WHERE  rn = 1 
   AND test.status IN ( 'X', 'Z' ) 
   AND a.tID = test.tID
```

Comment: Why aren't the condition in the `IN (SELECT ...)`'s WHERE just part of the WHERE the IN is a part of? And why mix implicit and explicit join notation?

Comment: _Bug:_  `CURRENT_DATE - 4` is nonsense.  Change to `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 DAY`.  See for yourself by running `SELECT CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE - 4;`.

Comment: What indexes do you have?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would change:

```
WHERE  a.tID IN (SELECT a.tID ....
```

into:

```
join ((SELECT a.tID FROM   ct.tab1 a ....) t on t.tID=a.tID
```

Answer (score 0):

`tID` is tab1's primary key. So when you say you are looking for `tab1` records the `tID` of which is found in a set of `tab1` records with status E, you could just as well simply say: I'm looking for `tab1` records with status E.

What your query does is: Show all `tab1` records with their final `tab2` status provided ...

- the `tab1` pmt is not null and not '{}'
- the `tab1` status is E
- the final `tab2` status is X or Z
- the final `tab2` status is due today or in the future
- there exists at least one `tab2` record due in the last three days for the `tab1` record

The query:

```
SELECT
  t1.tID,
  t1.sor_acct_id,
  t1.pmt,
  t2.status
FROM ct.tab1 t1
join
(
  SELECT
    tID,
    status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tID ORDER BY dueDate DESC) AS rn
  FROM ct.tab2
  WHERE dueDate > CURRENT_DATE - 1
) t2 ON  t2.tID = tab1.tID AND t2.rn = 1 AND t2.status IN ('X', 'Z') 
WHERE t1.status = 'E'
  AND t1.pmt IS NOT NULL
  AND t1.pmt <> '{}'
  and t1.tID IN
  (
    SELECT tID
    FROM ct.tab2
    WHERE dueDate > CURRENT_DATE - 4
      AND dueDate < CURRENT_DATE
  );
```